# Flot chart won't draw my points

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, flot

[image]

My problem lies here in this picture. I am trying to draw a graph with sensor data as my points (X,y). When the webpage loads it reads a csv files and sends this data to an ajax call from my codebhind. This is what my code behind is returning:

```
var myData = new Stats { 
                Time = dataContainer.time,
                LhXVals = dataContainer.lhXVals,
                LhYVals = dataContainer.lhYVals,
                LhZVals = dataContainer.lhZVals,
                RhXVals = dataContainer.rhXVals,
                RhYVals = dataContainer.rhYVals
            };
```

Here is what my Stats class looks like. I parse the data then store it in Lists. 
[image]

I then send this to the ajax call. Here is my success function for the ajax:

```
        var time = new Array();
        var lhXVals = new Array();
        var cumulative = new Array();
        var data2;

success: function (result) {
                        time = result.d.Time; //Time is a List<double>
                        lhXVals = result.d.LhXVals; //Left-Hand-X-Values is a List<double>, both are the same size

                        //check if time and lhXVals are empty, if not proceed
                        if (time.length > 0 || lhXVals.legnth > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < time.length; ++i) {
                                //only grabbing little bit of data just to test, 
                                //only taking first 2 elements
                                if (i == 6)
                                    break;
                                //use the time data ex:(510.2838439) as my X-axes
                                //use the left-hand-X-Values ex:(23.9384384) as my Y-axes
                                debugger;
                                cumulative.push([parseFloat(time[i]), parseFloat(lhXVals[i])]);//data2 was a manually populated example i used before
                                data2 = [[4.53123342, 0], [4.9039293, 24.89323233], [6, 0], [6, -12.134], [8, 0], [8, 6.932]];

                                //an index in the "cumulative" array would look like this:
                                // [0]: [510.2838439,23.9384384]
                            }
                        }
                        updateOnce(cumulative);
```

the `updateOnce(cumulative);` function accepts my cumulative array of points which i use in my `flot.setData()` method to draw the new graph.

```
function updateOnce(cumulative) {
                debugger;
                plot.setData([cumulative]);
                plot.draw();//draws nothing
            }
```

However the big problem is that when the `plot.draw();` gets drawn there is nothing on my chart and I have no clue why. I've tried everything I can think of. I've tried parsing the data to float, and leaving it but doesn't changing anything. My data in " cumulative" is stored precisely the same as the manual array(var data) I created for graph points but it just won't work and I've been pulling my hair out.

**EDIT**
For the comment below. I initially set it up like this :

```
function updateOnce(cumulative) {
                debugger;
                plot.setData([cumulative]);
                plot.draw(); //draws nothing
            }

            //implementing getData Last
            var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [getData()], {
                series: {
                    shadowSize: 0   // Drawing is faster without shadows
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: -50,
                    max: 50
                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: true
                }
            });
```

I return data which is a manually set array of points(x,y) so it will draw something first on the graph, which it does. Then when the ajax finally returns some data, I initiate the redraw with the returned data.

Comment: How do you initially draw the chart?  You'll need to call `plot.setupGrid()` after the `setData` to recalculate your axeses.

Comment: I added the initial setup in the question at the bottom

Comment: can you write that as an answer so i can accept it? I didn't realize it changed the axis, once I added the .setupGrid() it worked :P. Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the axes min/max change on a `setData` call you need to call `plot.setupGrid()` to recalculate the axeses.  From the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods), bolding mine:

> setData(data)
>
> You can use this to reset the data used. **Note that axis scaling,
>   ticks, legend etc. will not be recomputed (use setupGrid() to do
>   that). You'll probably want to call draw() afterwards.**
>
> You can use this function to speed up redrawing a small plot if you
>   know that the axes won't change. Put in the new data with
>   setData(newdata), call draw(), and you're good to go. Note that for
>   large datasets, almost all the time is consumed in draw() plotting the
>   data so in this case don't bother.
>
> setupGrid()
>
> Recalculate and set axis scaling, ticks, legend etc.
>
> Note that because of the drawing model of the canvas, this function
>   will immediately redraw (actually reinsert in the DOM) the labels and
>   the legend, but not the actual tick lines because they're drawn on the
>   canvas. You need to call draw() to get the canvas redrawn.